# FCC certified module in europe

Tags: rf, fcc, ce

If I have an FCC certified BLE module, can I use it in a product destined for Europe and CE mark the product with no additional (intentional radiator) testing?

Comment: Nice to see someone tries to do something properly. Global webshops have made possible to sell and purchase stuff where certification stamps are not worth more than the ink they contain. Authorities here in far west have no way to prevent a criminal which hides in a place like Wuanhungtsouhai  to produce and sell his low-cost "genuine" Sony or Hitachi counterfeits which radiate like a radio station and have direct connection from mains AC input to touchable parts.

Comment: @user287001 That EU and USA uses different radio standards has nothing to do with that though, it's just made that way politically, to prevent export and free trade. Specifically, greedy authorities in USA (and Canada) charge you a one time free beyond the EMC testing costs. Now _that_ should be criminal - no such thing exists in EU for license-free bands. I'm not up to date with the technical specifics in this case, but EN/ETSI 300 328 vs FCC Part 15C will likely boil down to similar technical requirements at least on the 2.4GHz band.

Answer (score 1):

Not likey. The regulations differ a bit. However:

1. If you still have the test results, you might be able to compare them to the EU standards and pass the tests
2. I heard that a lot of manufacturers just slap on the CE marking and only test for compliance when their compliance is challenged. (At court or somewhere else). When you are confident it will pass, you could do this.

Disclaimer: I only did some research on this matter and have no real life experience whatsoever, so take this with a pinch of salt or mostly some general guidance on which to conduct your own research.

Answer (score 1):

If your module is soldered or connected to a system that you designed, you have to go to an EMC lab and do some tests.

Not all, but just some.

For example, you will have to do the output power test.

This is true in Europe but I guess that holds in the US as well.

When coming to Europe from FCC you need to have a CB Report. It's basically paper.

That paper contains for example the extra tests you need to do to comply to European CE regulations.

UL, TUV and many others do that all the time.

https://gma.ul.com/about/cbscheme/